# AppData Folder Redirection manual registry change

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

We have app data folder redirection group policy in place. We are moving back to local appdata which is currently redirected to network share. Also, the option to move the contents to new location in gpo is enabled. On many occasions the policy is failing due to content move with several reasons (256 character limit, permission issues, etc).

My question is lets say hypothetically disabling the move content to new location in GPO is not an option here. I am changing the registry HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders  AppData to %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming on user’s laptop, getting the user to reboot the machine. After that, when user logs in, the GPO will now check the registry which is already set to local, it will not move the contents and successfully complete the policy. I have tested and it works.

This may not be right way of doing it, will there be any issues using this method going forward in terms of user’s app data location ?